# Increase the height of TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, containers

I want to increase the second TextField's height(Inside Stack). I have wrapped it in Container, and set the height to `500`, but it doesn't make any difference.

```
class _ABC extends State<ABC>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Add Data'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.done),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                              const Radius.circular(5.0))),
                      hintText: Localization.of(context).name,
                      labelText: Localization.of(context).name,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 500.0,          
                          child: TextField(
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      const Radius.circular(5.0))),
                              hintText: Localization.of(context).name,
                              labelText: Localization.of(context).name,
                            ),
                          )),
                      Positioned(
                        left: 5.0,
                        child: Icon(Icons.camera),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ])));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of a TextField is set either with

1) Expand to fill it's holder with **expands** or

2) Set it to a fixed height in lines, with **maxlines**.

Here's what you need to fill the container:

```
Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: 500.0,
    color: Colors.amber,
  child: TextField(
    expands: true,
    maxLines: null,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(5.0))),
      hintText: Localization.of(context).name,
      labelText: Localization.of(context).name,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

try to add below code inside `TextFormField`, you don't have to set the height to `Container`

```
TextFormField(
 .......
 keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
 maxLines: 5,// change the value of maxlines according to your requirement
),
```

Output

[image]